# ON GPS and data connection in phone automatically

Tags: android

How can I on data connection and GPS connection in android phone through my app automatically? So that my app can send mail and track GPS location.

Comment: Well all versions of Android (API Levels) does not support (Allow) this.

Comment: Can u please tell me which all versions support this feature?

Comment: Lower then Android L. Android L onwards google applied restriction on changing settings programatically.

Comment: your phone is rooted or not ?

Comment: My phone is not rooted yet. @user7345006

Comment: Mine phone is working in Marshmallow... So is there any way to implement this? My app needs to automatically on GPS and data connection...

Comment: Nop i guess its not possible.